# Objective-C hidden static method calling

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I google this question and spend some time to figure it out by myself but with a bad luck.

I need to call class's static method which is hidden for class's user.

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@end

// MyClass.m

@implementation MyClass

- (NSString *)myInstanceMethod
{
    return @"result string";
}

+ (NSString *)myStaticMethod
{
    return @"result string";
}

@end

------------------------------------------------------------

// MyCallerClass.m
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyCallerClass

- (void) testMethod
{
    MyClass *inst = [MyClass new];
    // call 1
    NSString *resultInstance    = [inst performSelector:@selector(myInstanceMethod)];
    // call 2
    NSString *resultStaitc      = [inst performSelector:@selector(myStaticMethod)];
    // call
    [MyClass myStaticMethod];
}

@end
```

Call 1 works good, Call 2 returns nil, Call 3 does not compile.

How can I call static method which does not defined in .h file and give correct returned object?

Thank in advance,
Rost

Comment: Objective-C has neither static nor private methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Call 2 ,

since it is an **class method** you should call like

```
NSString *resultStaitc      = [[inst class] performSelector:@selector(myStaticMethod)];
```

inst is the object.To call a class method you must call with class.
The object instance's class is supposed to be calling the method, not the instance itself.

For call 3

It should be working fine,The result value is never used .the compile error is because

```
+ (NSString *)myStaticMethod;
```

not declared in .h

use

```
NSString *resultStaitc1   =[MyClass myStaticMethod];
```

and it will return the value to the `resultStaitc1`

Comment: >> It wont work since declared private

Yes, you right, but I don't want make it public. I just want test how it works from my unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to declare an informal protocol for MyClass at the top of MyCallerClass.m. An informal protocol is just a category interface without the implementation block. You can stick you method declaration(s) in there. It does raise synchronisation problems between the two source files, but so does performSelector:. Doing it this way lets you call methods that have a different signature to just take [0-2] object arguments and return and object.

Comment: Yes, I believe it will work but for my case (which I did not describe in the question) it doesn't fit. I'm writing unit tests for code which I can not to change. But anyway thank you for you attention.